# Trouble fitting a Mixed Effects Model in lme4 - Interaction and 1 random effect

Tags: model, modeling, lme4, effects, mixed

Very much new to R. I'm currently trying to fit a mixed effect model to my data in lme4 to see if there is an interaction between my two fixed effects (GroupSize and Rank) with one random effect (ID).

Here's my code:

**mod <- lmer (SubFleeIndex ~ GroupSize
* Rank + (1|ID))**

The error message I keep getting back is:

**Error: number of levels of each grouping factor must be < number of observations (problems: ID)**

but I'm not entirely sure what this is telling me! I have set ID as a factor so it does not think it is a continuous variable but I'm not sure what else is stopping me from progressing. Any help is massively appreciated, thanks.

Comment: You have to specify the data somehow. Something like this: `mod <- lmer (SubFleeIndex ~ GroupSize * Rank + (1|ID), data = df)` Where `df` is the name of your dataframe

Comment: There could be a host of other problems, but we need a reproducible example to be able to help out: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Thanks both, I actually fixed it in the end anyway!

The issue was with ID only having one level as a random effect, I've switched it for GroupID (has 2 levels) and the models work.